# How to properly iterate through a list of map records or an array to get required values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with [neo4j database](https://github.com/neo4j-php/neo4j-php-client).

**Here is my code**

```
    <?php

require ('vendor/autoload.php');
$client = Laudis\Neo4j\ClientBuilder::create()
    ->addHttpConnection('backup', 'http://neo4j:foodisgood56@localhost')
    ->addBoltConnection('default', 'bolt://neo4j:foodisgood56@localhost')
    ->setDefaultConnection('default')
    ->build();
    
    $query = $client->run('MATCH (n:Dept1) RETURN n LIMIT 25');
    print_r($query );
    
    /*
    echo $json = json_decode($query, true);
    foreach($json as $v1){
    
    echo $v1['location'];
    echo $v1['dname'];
    echo $v1['deptno'];
    
    }
    */
    
    ?>
```

I have successfully query records from neo4j graph database.

Here is my issue. When printing a record in the array, I have the following output:

```
Ds\Vector Object ( [0] => Ds\Map Object ( [0] => Ds\Pair Object ( [key] => n [value] => Array ( [location] => Hyderabad [dname] => Accounting [deptno] => 10 ) ) ) [1] => Ds\Map Object ( [0] => Ds\Pair Object ( [key] => n [value] => Array ( [location] => Hyderabad1 [dname] => Accounting1 [deptno] => 11 ) ) ) [2] => Ds\Map Object ( [0] => Ds\Pair Object ( [key] => n [value] => Array ( [location] => Hyderabad2 [dname] => Accounting2 [deptno] => 12 ) ) ) )
```

How can I iterate through the list of maps or array to get or display values for **location, dname and deptno**?

Comment: Step by step. Print out what `$v1` is (inside your `foreach()`), then you will see that that variable is iterable ...so create another `foreach($v1 as $subarray)`, then print out what `$subarray` is.  Repeat until you find what you are after.  I suspect at some point you'll need to iterate `$variable['value']`.  (you should have presented us with the array-type data in your question instead of the object-type data.)  If `$query` is not json, then you can just as easily iterate that object step-by-step.  I don't use neo4j, so this is just a hint.

Comment: Thanks **@Mickmackusa**
The output is a map list.
`Ds\Vector Object ( [0] => Ds\Map Object ( [0] => Ds\Pair Object ( [key] => n [value] => Array ( [location] => Hyderabad [dname] => Accounting [deptno] => 10 ) ) ) [1] => Ds\Map Object ( [0] => Ds\Pair Object ( [key] => n [value] => Array ( [location] => Hyderabad1 [dname] => Accounting1 [deptno] => 11 ) ) ) [2] => Ds\Map Object ( [0] => Ds\Pair Object ( [key] => n [value] => Array ( [location] => Hyderabad2 [dname] => Accounting2 [deptno] => 12 ) ) ) )`

 foreach() loop, it throws Warning: `foreach() argument must be of type array|object`

Comment: So does the documentation tell you how to cast it to a standard array/object?  Can you use `(array)$query` or `json_decode(json_encode($query), true)`?

Comment: https://github.com/neo4j-php/neo4j-php-client/blob/main/README.md#reading-a-result  Looks like they have their own methods.

Comment: Please resolve this page in an **educational** fashion by posting an answer to your question.  I would prefer to upvote your answer, but it needs to be _good/helpful_ and include some explanation with the snippet. In time, please remember to award the green tick to your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The outputted record has to be json decode and json encode and must be set to true. the property n is a value used as part of the database queries as can be seen in my post above

```
$json = json_decode(json_encode($query), true);
//print_r($json);
$location = $json[0]['n']['location'];
$dname = $json[0]['n']['dname'];
```